# Truncated SVD in Scikit-learn: How to Get Output Data Back?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svd

I am trying to reduce the number of columns in my dataframe using `SVD` in *Scikit-learn*.

The code below runs but I don't know how to access the transformed dataframe.

My original dataframe is called `df_SVD` and its shape is (8844, 1159). When I run the code below and look for the shape of `df_SVD` after the transformation, the shape stays the same.

```
svd=TruncatedSVD(n_components=20, n_iter=10)
svd.fit_transform(df_SVD)
df_SVD.head()
df_SVD.shape
df_SVD_new.shape
```

Comment: Try to `df_SVD_new = svd.fit_transform(df_SVD)`

Comment: Thanks @E.Z.. This worked to get me the output in an ndarray. But my goal was to use the results of the Truncated SVD to then run DBSCAN clustering in scikit-learn. I have a very wide table with shape of (8844, 1159) and I wanted to reduce dimension of the input dataset to use for clustering. But looking at the output, I don't know how to format it into a DBSCAN-ready dataframe.

Comment: I assume `df_SVD` only contains features. After you have transformed it to `df_SVD_new` you may fit DBSCAN cluster with it. There should not be any problems with fitting. You may look [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-dbscan-py). In the example, they simply preprocess data with `StandardScaler`, but the logic is the same.

Comment: Did you find out how to transform the array so you can feed it to DBSCAN again? My kernel keeps crashing if I try to do so.